# Stop server-sent events by server

Tags: http, web-applications, server-sent-events

When using server-sent events, how does server communicate to browser that there won't be more events and that it should close the sse connection?

Is this a part of the protocol or should this be implemented by passing hint in normal event to the client that it can close event source ?

Answer (score 0):

The server-sent events is yet another [streaming technique which is one of ways of Comet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_(programming)#Streaming). To stop streaming data, just close the connection in server. You don't need to let client call `close` method of `EventSource` instance.

FYI, the following links show that how [Cettia](http://cettia.io) streaming transport backed by server-sent events implements to close connection. (Note that I'm an author of Cettia)

- Java server - https://github.com/cettia/cettia-java-server/blob/1.0.0-Beta1/server%2Fsrc%2Fmain%2Fjava%2Fio%2Fcettia%2Ftransport%2Fhttp%2FHttpTransportServer.java#L358
- JavaScript client - https://github.com/cettia/cettia-javascript-client/blob/1.0.0-Beta1/cettia.js#L884-L886

---

**Edit**

For that issue, I added [es.close within es.onerror](https://github.com/cettia/cettia-javascript-client/blob/1.0.0-Beta1/cettia.js#L878-L882).

Comment: The app is implemented in  node.js and after trying several ways to close/finish the connection the browser (Chrome) repeats the request instead of forgetting about it.

Comment: According to http://html5doctor.com/server-sent-events/#properties) "if the connection drops, the EventSource fires an error event and automatically tries to reconnect. The server can also control the timeout before the client tries to reconnect."

Comment: You're right. I recall that I [added es.close within es.onerror](https://github.com/cettia/cettia-javascript-client/blob/1.0.0-Beta1/cettia.js#L878-L882) for that issue. Sorry for the confusion.